# Error printing on Epson TM-U220 USB

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a situation with an Epson POS Printer. The example provided by Epson works as expected, but when I try to use in Xamarin BOOM!

I created a Android Java Bindings Library, adding a folder "Jars" and copy the `ePos-Prin.jar` file inside it, with the option `EmbeddedJar` as `Build Action`.

On my Android project, I put the .so file (native library) inside "jni/armeabi" folder tree, with the Build Action selected to `AndroidNativeLibrary`. Also in the Android project I have a simple `MainActivity` class which will try to find the printer, but exception cannot be thrown.

I'm using the following lines of codes:

```cs
using System;    
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Com.Epson.Epsonio; //Library from JBL
using Com.Epson.Eposprint; //Library from JBL

namespace EpsonPrint
{
    [Activity(MainLauncher=true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        const int SEND_TIMEOUT = 10 * 1000;
        DeviceInfo[] mDeviceList;
        Context mContext;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            //Java.Lang.JavaSystem.Load("$APP/jni/libeposprint.so"); //Doesn't work

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            var find = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.find);
            var print = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.print);

            mContext = this;

            print.Click += delegate
                {
                    try {
                        Print();
                    } catch (EpsonIoException e) {
                        e.PrintStackTrace();
                        Toast.MakeText(mContext, e.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
                    }
                };

            find.Click += delegate
            {
                    try {
                        GetDevices(); //BOOM! here...
                    } catch (EpsonIoException e) {
                        e.PrintStackTrace();
                        Toast.MakeText(mContext, e.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
                    }
            };
        }

        private void GetDevices() {

            try {
                Finder.Start(this, DevType.Usb, "null");
            } catch (EpsonIoException e) {
                if (e.Status == IoStatus.ErrIllegal) {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "SEARCH ALREADY IN PROGRESS", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                } else if (e.Status == IoStatus.ErrProcessing) {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "COULD NOT EXECUTE PROCESS", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                } else if (e.Status == IoStatus.ErrParam) {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "INVALID PARAMETER PASSED", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                } else if (e.Status == IoStatus.ErrMemory) {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "COULD NOT ALLOCATE MEMORY", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                } else if (e.Status == IoStatus.ErrFailure) {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "UNSPECIFIED ERROR", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                }
            }
        }

        private void Print()
        {
            mDeviceList = Finder.GetDeviceInfoList(Finder.FilterNone);

            var status = new int[1];

            if (mDeviceList.Length > 0)
            {
                Finder.Stop();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.MakeText(mContext, "List is null", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }

            String deviceName = mDeviceList[0].DeviceName;
            String printerName = mDeviceList[0].PrinterName;
            int deviceType = mDeviceList[0].DeviceType;
            String macAddress = mDeviceList[0].MacAddress;
            Print printer = new Print(ApplicationContext);

            //Log.("Device Name: " + deviceName +"\n" + "Printer Name: " + printerName + "\n" + "Device Type: " + String.valueOf(deviceType) + "\n" + "MAC: " +macAddress, "");

            try
            {

                //Print Data Builder
                var builder = new Builder("TM-U220", Builder.ModelAnk, ApplicationContext);
                builder.AddText("ESPON PRINT TEST");
                builder.AddCut(Builder.CutFeed);

//                if(builder!=null) {
//                    Log.i("BUILDER NOT NULL", "");
//                }

                //Printer Test Builder
                var confirmBuilder = new Builder("TM-U220", Builder.ModelAnk, ApplicationContext);

                //Open printer
                printer.OpenPrinter(DevType.Usb, deviceName);

                //Send Test Builder
                printer.SendData(confirmBuilder, SEND_TIMEOUT, status);

                //Check printer Status
                if ((status[0] & Com.Epson.Eposprint.Print.StOffLine) != Com.Epson.Eposprint.Print.StOffLine)
                {
                    //If online send print data
                    //Log.i("PRINTER NOT OFFLINE", "");
                    printer.SendData(builder, SEND_TIMEOUT, status);

                    //Check if data sent successfully
                    if ((status[0] & Com.Epson.Eposprint.Print.StPrintSuccess) == Com.Epson.Eposprint.Print.StPrintSuccess)
                    {
                        builder.ClearCommandBuffer();
                        Toast.MakeText(this, "DATA SENT SUCCESSFULLY", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                    }
                    printer.ClosePrinter();
                }
                else if ((status[0] & Com.Epson.Eposprint.Print.StOffLine) == Com.Epson.Eposprint.Print.StOffLine)
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "PRINTER OFFLINE", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "OTHER PRINTER ERROR", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                }
            }
            catch (EposException e)
            {
                e.PrintStackTrace();

                Toast.MakeText(mContext, e.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Where does it go "Boom"? I don't have any Epson printer, so it is hard to help you debug this. But you have the code, you have the debugger attached, step through it and find the exact place it throws.

Comment: Xamarin Studio only show a Java.Lang Exception "EpsonIoException" but the cach block never fires. "Boom" is on this line Finder.Start(this, DevType.Usb, "null");

Comment: And you have tried catching all exceptions there?

Comment: Yeap! have 2 catches. EpsonIoException and Exception. But never fires anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Epson USB printer, but I tried the following simple piece of code in various printers and I can tell you that works. 
Have a look if you can somehow create a file of what you want to print and then try this simple method below, maybe it also works in that printer:

```
public void print () {
        Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
        try {
            desktop.print(new File("Docfile.pdf"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Will not work on Xamarin.Android. May be on Java. I'm using Xamarin. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yeah I noticed soon after posting that you are doing Android. I just added the tag. Sorry :( Good Luck